# code to access the singleton class file instead of calling the method every time

Tags: java, data-structures

This is the method I'm calling from another class like 10 times:

```
new ScribbleInput().getString("Call", getUiDevice());
```

How can I call it from a singleton class?

Comment: Just like you do it for any other class. Or can you please post some more details into your question?

Comment: Make it static the getString method

Comment: @RohitJain i want to create a new class...and then call it

Comment: @RohitJain and how can i call this singelton class from the class where i am actually calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here because you didn't provide much in the way of details.  You could do this:

```
class ScribbleInput {
    private static ScribbleInput INSTANCE = new ScribbleInput();
    private ScribbleInput() {}

    public static String getString(String foo, String bar) {
        return INSTANCE.getString(foo, bar);
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to the class itself, you could wrap it with another object that acts as a proxy.  If you give me more detail I should be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: new ScribbleInput().getString("Call", getUiDevice());
here ScribbleInput is a class and i'm calling its method getString which will parse the "CALL" string. So here
 new ScribbleInput().getString("Call", getUiDevice());
i am calling it for more than 10 times in my class. So what i want to do is create a singelton file so that i dont have to write
new ScribbleInput().getString("Call", getUiDevice());
10 times and i can simply call the singelton class that will do it.

Comment: 1. They are not files, they are classes.
2. If I'm reading this right, all you're really looking for is a utility method on your class that calls this thing.

Why not just add a utility method like

    private String getCallString(Object uiDevice) {
        return new ScribbleInput().getString("Call", uiDevice);
    }

Or you can simply cache an instance of ScribbleInput to reuse if it is truly stateless.

At some point you have to deal with the fact that Java is a relatively verbose language.

Comment: ok so they are classes. I have to create a singelton class because i can use when it with other classes too.

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be a singleton.  You can create a new utility class with a static method to perform this action for you.  However, it does not need to be singleton... in fact you never need to instantiate it.

Comment: even i think so but my team lead wants to have a singelton class.

Comment: He must have a reason - or so I have to hope.  The only difference between a singleton and a class with only static methods and a private constructor is the fact that a singleton has a private static instance of itself.

Comment: can you post the answer...if you know how to do it?

Comment: The answer I posted *is* a singleton.  Just change the name.

Comment: it gives me error in 
public static String getString(String foo, String bar) {
        return INSTANCE.getString(foo, bar);
    }